# Adding a view.py to a flask web application

Tags: python, flask

I just started working with web tools and `flask`.I have a `python` script with 9 functions and I am trying to make a flask application. the main view of this application would do the same thing as my python script (in which some functions are intermediate meaning they do not produce the final output and 2 functions produce the final output). since for one route I have 9 functions, what do you suggest? shall I rename my original script as `view.py` and call it in the `app.py` (under the corresponding route) or there is better way?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a separate file is always a better choice. It will make the code more readable and understandable. 
Simply create a file and call the method in app.py like this.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from views import your_method_name

# Initialize the app
app = Flask(__name__)

# Route (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:5000/my-url)
@app.route("/my-url", methods=['POST'])
def parse():

    response = your_method_name() # call the method
    return jsonify(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```